# Code Repeated Measures and distribution in R from SAS

Tags: r, gamma-distribution

I have the following code in SAS, and I need to recreate this model for the same data set in R.  I am having trouble finding the proper code to recreate the model, especially changing the distribution of the data to a gamma distribution.

SAS Code

```
proc glimmix data=combined plot=(residualpanel studentpanel);
class block pen hour daymod;
model mean=hour|pen/solution ddfm=kr dist=gamma;
random _residual_/ subject=steer type=cs;
random block;
random intercept /subject=pen;
lsmeans hour/cl plots=meanplot;
output out=FinalModel pred=p resid=r lcl=lowlimit ucl=uplimit;
run;
```

Any Help would be Appreciated

Comment: try something along the lines of `library("lme4"); glmer(...,family=Gamma)`.  (The `...` is left for someone else.  You're going to have trouble implementing the compound symmetry (`type="cs"`) option at the moment.)